# Can't get variables to add up

Tags: javascript

So I have this code which is supposed to calculate the total price of a product. Yet it only shows the last added value that should be added to the price.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var dig_print = 0
  var up_op = 0
document.querySelector("#div1").onclick = function() {
  var dig_print = 1
  var total = up_op + dig_print
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total
  }

document.querySelector("#div2").onclick = function() {
  var dig_print = 2
  var total = up_op + dig_print;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total
  }
document.querySelector("div.3").onclick = function() {
  var up_op = 10
  var total = up_op + dig_print
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total
  }
document.querySelector("div.4").onclick = function() {
  var up_op = 20
  var total = up_op + dig_print
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total
  }
}
```

Comment: don't declare total again in the functions, that should fix it

Comment: Because you're overriting `up_op` in your last 2 functions

Comment: So total should either display 1+10, 2+10 or 1+20, 2+20 right?

Answer (score 0):

First, var `total` should be declared as global var (see the code snippet below). Also, don't declare `up_op` in the body of the function (i.e. remove that `var` in front of `up_op` from each function):

```
window.onload = function() {
  var dig_print = 0;
  var up_op = 0;
  var total = 0;
// the rest of your code
```

This will fix the problem you have described.

Answer (score 0):

don't declare `total` again in the functions, that should fix it.

*If you define a variable with name `total` inside a function it's a different variable with scope limited to the function.*

Same is the case with your `dig_print` and `up_op` variables both declared multiple times.

*You tried to add values to globally defined `total` variable, whereas in fact you created multiple local copies with scope limited to those funntions which finally gets displayed*

Also please go through this excellent article on [Demystifying JavaScript Variable Scope and Hoisting](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

```
window.onload = function() {
  var dig_print = 0;
  var up_op = 0;
var total = 0;
document.querySelector("#div1").onclick = function() {
  //var dig_print = 1// why declare this again ??
  total = up_op + dig_print
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total
  }

document.querySelector("#div2").onclick = function() {
  //dig_print = 2 // why declare this ??
  total = up_op + dig_print;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total
  }
document.querySelector("div.3").onclick = function() {
  //up_op = 10;// why declare this ??
  total = up_op + dig_print
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total
  }
document.querySelector("div.4").onclick = function() {
  //up_op = 20// why declare this ??
  total = up_op + dig_print
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = total
  }
}
```